# При считывании данных с текстового поля ввода не могу получить первое число

Tags: javascript, html, css

У меня есть поле ввода. С этого поля мне нужно получать первую одну цифру. Это я делаю следующим кодом. Но при первом клике я получаю NaN, а при последующих все работает нормально. Мне нужна только первая цифра.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  //get data from inputs
  var numb = document.getElementById("card_number");

  function showNumber() {
    var b = document.getElementById("card_number").value;
    console.log(+b[0]);
  };


  numb.addEventListener("keypress", showNumber);
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="card_number" class="card-number" maxlength="23">
```

Answer (score 2):

При первом вызове `keypress` у вас в поле `''` (пустая строка),
`''[0]` - `undefined`,
`+undefined` - `NaN`
Дальше уже в инпуте есть значение, соответственно `inputValue[0]` является первым символом строки, а "+" делает приведение типов что-то типа `+'1' === 1`

Что же касается "Что я делаю не так?" - зависит от того, что вы вообще пытаетесь сделать ...

Answer (score 2):

```js
window.onload = function() {
  //get data from inputs
  var numb = document.getElementById("card_number");

  function showNumber() {

    var getNum = [...document.getElementById("card_number").value];
    console.log(getNum[0]);
  };


  numb.addEventListener("keyup", showNumber);
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="card_number" class="card-number" maxlength="23"> С
```

Comment: У вас опечатка "getNum" а в след строке "grtNum"

Comment: @AndrewB, благодарю....  я ее увидел))) но не то исправил)))

Comment: Спасибо, я решил немного по-другому. Я определяю код клавиши события. event.keyCode.

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста, но думаю не плохо было бы, если бы мы увидели решение...  Оформи ответ и выложи свое решение...

Answer (score 0):

А дальше я уже через цикл выбираю нужные мне цифры по кодам клавиш

```js
window.onload = function() {
  //get data from inputs
  var numb = document.getElementById("card_number");
  var logo = document.getElementById("logo");

  function showNumber() {
    var a = event.keyCode
    console.log(a);
  };

  numb.addEventListener("keyup", showNumber);
};
```

```html
<input type="text" id="card_number" class="card-number" maxlength="23">
```